# driver.navigate().back() not working in java in intellij

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get back to previous page by using back() method using. using intellij and chromedriver. But back() method is failing here..

My code is as follows,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class test {


public static WebDriver driver;


@BeforeTest
public void initiateAction()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}


@Test
public void Login() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.get("https://www.sportsmediawatch.com/nba-tv-schedule/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().back();
    Thread.sleep(5000);



    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: Code looks good to me can you try with some simple URL which is getting loaded easily. Also try increasing thread.sleep or explicitely wait for any element.

Comment: Move `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000,TimeUnit.SECONDS);` to `initiateAction()`.